# XeLaTeX Errors on Windows 7

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to get a minimal XeLaTeX document to compile in Windows 7 with MiKTeX 2.9. I have updated all of my installed MikTeX packages and am still getting many errors during compilation.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I get a working document after hitting return through a lot of errors, but it has some debugging comments at the beginning of the pdf. See below:

[image: Output]

Here are the first errors of the log file:

```
\l_fontspec_tmp_int=\count122
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 1893.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 1897.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 1901.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 1905.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl 
                                fontspec/Ligatures/Historical
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl 
                                fontspec/Ligatures/Historic
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}

? 
))) (C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\lipsum\lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count123
)
Requested font "Adobe Garamond Pro" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.otf
Requested font "Adobe Garamond Pro/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.otf

! Undefined control sequence.
\fontspec_get_features:n ...st ,#1}\str_if_eq:xxF 
                                                  {\l_fontspec_hexcol_tl \l_...
l.4 ...mainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

The complete logfile can be found here: [template.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mecckp3ny1azu2p/template.log)

I get the same results using any number of installed system fonts. I'd like to get the document to compile correctly without errors and to leave out the extra information at the beginning of the resultant pdf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Update your system.

Comment: Your `fontspec` (you: 2012/05/06 v2.2b – me: 2013/03/16 v2.3a) and `xetex.def` (you: 2009/11/22 v0.94 – me: 2013/02/04 v0.95) are older than mine, while your `xparse` (you:  2013/03/12 v4467 – me: 2012/11/21 v4332) is more recent. Strange. One way or the other, a `xetex.def` from 2009 doesn’t sound good.

Comment: Never mind the `xparse`, that was just a quirk of my system. Now I’m at v4467 as well and the picture is clear: Your system is indeed not up to date and you should update. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473).